# NAO - Accessing and Using Virtual Nao

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

I am currently working with virtual nao on Choregraphe, I know it is possible to connect and access the representation of virtual nao on Choregraphe but is there any way to work with Robot View (or similar application) as a standalone app?

For example, is there any way that I can run a python script and open only Robot View of Virtual Nao (or similar application) to just track the Nao?

I have tried to use V-rep and Webots. Connected virtual nao to both of those mentioned applications but I could not detach virtual nao as a standalone application.

Comment: No, not really. I believe it's a built-in part of Choregraphe (though the Android Studio Pepper SDK includes a standalone robot-viewer as part of it, you'd need the source code to build a standalone version for Python with NAO). 
Can I ask what your goal is for this? There are other NAO simulators which might do what you want.

Comment: My goal is here to use virtual representation of Nao robot to interact. To be honest, simulators do not matter at this point. I just need to use virtual nao as a standalone app and some behavior packages of it (I uploaded some behavior packages to virtual nao and can run & access from choreographe). But as I mentioned before I do not want to connect choregraphe just to run Nao since I need to embed it to some GUI or similar application.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible. Especially if you want behaviours to run and interact with the virtual robot, you really need Choregraphe to be running to use the use the NAO APIs.If you want to use virtual NAO to show off to others, I think your best bet would be to show the robot view on half the screen, and your app on the other. If you need to package your own app, you might need to look at other open source simulators or develop your own virtual robot.